# Kubuntu login screen does not show network

Tags: wireless, 18.04, kubuntu, login-screen

I have Kubuntu 18.04 but the login screen does not show the network. i.e the WiFi connection. Already, I have a wifi connection available to all users and it connect automatically and I ask for any that should allows this connection to be displayed on the login screen like Gnome. Does it possible?

**Edit**

> I have submitted [bug as a wish-list](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=401551) to KDE development team about
>   this feature.

Comment: I don't think this aspect is customizable at the user level. By the way, I checked Lubuntu (Bionic and Cosmic), Xubuntu (Bionic), and Ubuntu Mate (Cosmic) and they too don't show the network status in the login screen. Maybe you could file a feature request (or enhancement) at https://github.com/sddm/sddm/issues.

Comment: And someone asked about it in 2016: https://github.com/sddm/sddm/issues/744

Comment: @DKBose the problem in the issue you regarded on GitHub, is that some people understand it like we need to have a connection before login, but indeed, we need the connection status and the ability of connecting before login or at least the status only.

Comment: Well, you'll have to make your case for including what you want in the first link I posted.